# Does MongoDB have a shell history file?

Tags: mongodb, history, interactive-shell

Does MongoDB have something like a `.bash_history` file?

I recently typed in a long command, closed & re-opened the shell, and want to retrieve it.

Pressing up doesn't work as it seems that the history of the last shell is not accessible in the new shell.

I installed 1.8.1 with Homebrew. Is there a configuration variable I should set that will turn on MongoDB interactive shell history logging?

Here's my `mongod.conf` file:

```
# Store data in /usr/local/var/mongodb instead of the default /data/db
dbpath = /usr/local/var/mongodb

# Only accept local connections
bind_ip = 127.0.0.1
# Enable Write Ahead Logging (not enabled by default in production deployments)
journal = true
```

Comment: It should be on already. Did you check to see if you have a ~/.dbshell?

Answer (score 50):

Yes, its in `~/.dbshell` as of version 1.8.1 which I am using. But this could be something they added in 1.7+ as from what I recall 1.6.5 does not have it.

Comment: still at ~/.dbshell location with MongoDB shell version v4.0.6 on Debian Linux

Comment: I can't find `.dbshell` for v6.0.7, but I found this file that appears to be the equivalent: `~/.mongodb/mongosh/mongosh_repl_history`

Answer (score 2):

of course yes,

it's in your home Path : `~/.dbshell` like lobster1234 said.
for windows you should check out the link https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/#files

but beware, you should save the contents in other file `(cat .dbshell >>Mongohistory.txt)` after you have used mongo shell, becouse mongodb shell don't ganna save the whole commandes that you have taped in.

Answer (score 2):

For windows, type the following in the powershell:

```
$ cat ~/.dbshell
```

Answer (score 1):

On Windows `cmd` you can type this command to see the history:

```
notepad %userprofile%\.dbshell
```

If you have VS code installed, this also works:

```
code %userprofile%\.dbshell
```